Iterate through large dictionary in python
I wrote this function in order to merge tax values based on a specific logic. It iterates over the tax dictionary, looking for keys that share a country code suffix and have overlapping values. When such keys are found, their values are merged, and the duplicate key is removed from the dictionary.
def merge_tax_values_new_logic(tax_dict):
    treated_list = set()
    while True:
        changed = False
        for key1, value1 in list(tax_dict.items()):
            country_code = key1[-2:]
            print('current list :',tax_dict)
            if key1 not in treated_list:
                print('current iteration key :' , key1) 
                for key2, value2 in list(tax_dict.items()):
                    if key2.endswith(country_code) and key1 != key2 and any(hl_id in value2 for hl_id in value1):
                        tax_dict[key1].extend(value2)
                        tax_dict.pop(key2)
                        tax_dict[key1] = list(set(tax_dict[key1]))
                        changed = True
                        print( 'current key : ' , key1 , 'matched  with key : ' , key2  ,  'state  of the dict after the pop : ', tax_dict)
                        break
            treated_list.add(key1)
            print('treated list :', treated_list)
            print('******************************')
            if changed:
                break
        if not changed:
            break
    return tax_dict

Example:
new_tax_dict = {'tax1_US':['A'],'tax2_US':['B'], 'tax3_US':['A','B']}
merge_tax_values_new_logic(new_tax_dict)

Result :
    current list : {'tax1_US': ['A'], 'tax2_US': ['B'], 'tax3_US': ['A', 'B']}
    current iteration key : tax1_US
    current key :  tax1_US matched  with key :  tax3_US state  of the dict after the pop :  {'tax1_US': ['A', 'B'], 'tax2_US': ['B']}
    treated list : {'tax1_US'}
    ******************************
    current list : {'tax1_US': ['A', 'B'], 'tax2_US': ['B']}
    treated list : {'tax1_US'}
    ******************************
    current list : {'tax1_US': ['A', 'B'], 'tax2_US': ['B']}
    current iteration key : tax2_US
    current key :  tax2_US matched  with key :  tax1_US state  of the dict after the pop :  {'tax2_US': ['A', 'B']}
    treated list : {'tax2_US', 'tax1_US'}
    ******************************
    current list : {'tax2_US': ['A', 'B']}
    treated list : {'tax2_US', 'tax1_US'}
    ******************************
    {'tax2_US': ['A', 'B']}

it works perfectly on small dict with few keys. However, performance is a real  issue when this function deals with large number of keys inside the dict (+40k keys and a mean count of values of 5 elements for each key).
Do you see any other alternatives ?
Regards,

If the only thing that matters is the country suffix, then why not just create the new dict with only the country suffix as the key? If the values need to be unique collections, why not just use a set?

Hi, I think the main problem is that you are iterating through non sorted list of keys. for key2, value2 in list(tax_dict.items()). This means that in worst case for every key you will go through full list of keys.
Solution: I would recommend to get sorted list of keys, basically sorted by last two symbols.
keys = sorted(data.keys(), key = lambda x: x[-2:]) Then smatrly interate in for with regards that all keys are sorted.

It's unclear (to me) how you decide to retain tax2_US rather than either of tax1_US or tax3_US

@SIGHUP, ideally it's the last key read, (but it's not important, since it's not handled in this function ! A business rule has to be defined in the future).
PS: it can't be  tax3_US since it's the fist key to be deleted from the dict after the first merge.

@KennyOstrom, I think this part of the original post explains well that it's not only about the country. "looking for keys that share a country code suffix and have overlapping values". You can suggest a modification if it stills not clear.

We were looking at specifically how and why to merge or drop some of the keys, but not others. I'll go with a solution where I just remember them all, but kind of on the side.

What you want are probably the connected components of a graph. The library networkx can do this easily. I tried to measure the speed but the sample data is too small for a useful result. I just guess it is faster than the original approach:
import networkx as nx
from itertools import repeat

def merge_tax_values_new_logic(tax_dict):
    graph = nx.Graph()

    representation = {}

    for key1, value1 in tax_dict.items():
        country_code = key1[-2:]
        nodes = list (zip(value1, repeat(country_code)))
        for n in nodes:
            representation[n] = key1
        graph.add_nodes_from(nodes)

        if len(value1) > 1:
            first = (value1[0], country_code)
            graph.add_edges_from(zip(repeat(first), zip(value1[1:], repeat(country_code))))

    result = {}
    
    for comps in nx.connected_components(graph):
        representer = representation[next(iter(comps))]
        result[representer] = [value for value, _ in comps]
        
    print(result)


new_tax_dict = {'tax1_US':['A'],'tax2_US':['B'], 'tax3_US':['A','B']}
merge_tax_values_new_logic(new_tax_dict)
        
new_tax_dict = {'tax1_US':['A'],'tax2_US':['B'], 'tax3_US':['A','B'] , 'tax4_US':['Z'] }
merge_tax_values_new_logic(new_tax_dict)

Output is not exactly the desired one but I think it is right:
{'tax3_US': ['B', 'A']}
{'tax3_US': ['B', 'A'], 'tax4_US': ['Z']}


I understand your frustration, optimisation of for loops may be very complex.
You have a very common problem where you are iterating through a list and have one more nested for that is iterating through it again. In such problems speed of execution might reach proxy of n^2 complexity (where n - number of keys in the dictionary). Most common solution here is to sort keys in a way to exclude nested for that iterates through the same list.
Solutioin:
I would recommend to get sorted list of tax keys, basically sorted by last two symbols.
keys = sorted(data.keys(), key = lambda x: x[-2:])
Then you may smartly iterate through all keys with regards that all keys are sorted.

def merge_tax_values_new_logic(tax_dict):

    def get_country(key: str) -> str:
        return key[-2:]
    
    # sorting keys and thus grouping keys by country code
    keys = sorted(tax_dict.keys(), key = lambda x: get_country(x))

    # maps: value -> key
    vals_map = {}
    group_country = None
    for key in keys:

        # start processing new country group
        if get_country(key) != group_country:
            group_country = get_country(key)
            vals_map = {}


        for val in tax_dict[key]:
            # if we seen one of the values before merge old tax_code to current
            prev_key = vals_map.get(val, None)
            if prev_key in tax_dict and key != prev_key:
                # found processed tax code with the same value
                # merge tax code to current
                tax_dict[key].extend(tax_dict.pop(prev_key))
        
        # depends on the data you might want to deduplicate tax_dict[key] somewhere here

        # update information about seen values
        for val in tax_dict[key]:            
            vals_map[val] = key

        
    return tax_dict


thank you for your answer but it's not only about the country suffix.  your function will group all by what you called group_country. In facts it's about the values too.
new_tax_dict = {'tax1_US':['A'],'tax2_US':['B'], 'tax3_US':['A','B'] , 'tax4_US':['Z'] }
merge_tax_values_new_logic(new_tax_dict)
would give : {'tax1_US': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'Z']} which is wrong for the purpose.
it has to be {'tax1_US': ['A', 'B'] , tax4_US : ['Z']} since no overlapping between values.

hmm... thx, yes, I've missed this part. Anyway sorting keys is a must before moving forward with dealing with overlapping items.

If it's not only about the country suffix, can you address that in the original question? Why can we drop tax1 and tax3 but not tax2?

@Safus09 are you considering memory limits? Or you are open to any solutions?
